# python application which has gui as well as console for user interaction

Tags: python

I am looking to create a python application in linux which should have a GUI interface as well as console for inputs . Console name what user want.

shell> python my_application.py  OR executable

my_app>       (opens gui too)

Can someone please help me get this or any link where I can learn this.

Thanks

Comment: Normally you choose one option, either Graphical or console. Users can't interact with both at the same time and you need more code when using both

Answer (score 0):

Look into learning [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) (easier) for making GUIs or [PyQt5](http://PyQt5) (better). Then, I'd use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to specify if you want to launch the GUI.